# Best Server For Java

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I'm starting in Java Web development, then i want to ask, what is the best server, like Apache Tomcat, Resin and others. Remember that i use Linux Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: Would you at least list what would make a "good" server?  And the term "server" is too general. Would you be more specific?

Comment: Fixed, it's a server to use with Servlets.

Comment: Why another down vote???????????

Comment: @Nathan: Improve your writing, it helps.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you're talking about JSP server for Java, just to keep things free, documented, and available I'd suggest Apache Tomcat.

I personally haven't done JSP development but you can find ubuntu documentation: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheTomcat5)  It will give instructions on serving servlets and jsp pages.

Answer (score 6):

The best server depends a lot on what you are trying to do.

If you just want to test simple webapps (JSP / Servlet) Tomcat is probably the easiest way. It is packaged in Ubuntu. The documentation for Tomcat on their website isnt as comprehensive as we could want, but you can easily find good books on Tomcat. There is now more and more good monitoring solutions for Tomcat, so Tomcat is bocoming a good solution even for large production deployements. (I waor in a private bank and we are moving away from BEA Weblogic for Tomcat).

If you want a robust enterprise grade server, JBoss or Glassfish are good solutions, but they are a bit harder to setup.

If you want a complete solution with very good monitoring, try BEA Weblogic. They have a developper version for free, but if you want to do production deployements, be ready to sepnd quite some money.

I have no experience with Resin, but I have heard good things about it ...

If you are using this server for developement, you'll need to see which server is well integrated with your IDE. Eclipse integrates very well with Tomcat, and also integrates with most open source app servers. Eclipse integration with Weblogic is not as good as it could be. Netbeans is known to integrates well with Glassfish (no surprise), but I dont use Netbeans.

My choice for a development server would be Tomcat, unless I was working on a project where I would really need EJBs. If the production server is already choosen (which is the case most of the time) I would try to use the same server for the dev, unless it is a very heavyweight server (like Weblogic). In this last case, I would try to use both Tomcat and Weblogic to have better velocity.

Answer (score 4):

[resin](http://caucho.com/resin/), [jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/). but really that depends on criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Windows server 2008.  It currently holds a performance record: See 
http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/018045_EN

from the page:

“This impressive world record on Windows Server 2008 demonstrates Oracle and AMD’s joint collaboration to optimize Java performance. It serves as a powerful proof point of the excellent TCO that can be obtained when running Oracle JRockit JVM on servers powered by the new 45nm Quad-Core AMD Opteron processor,” said Earl Stahl, vice president, Software Development, AMD.

Oracle JRockit delivered 1,181,782 SPECjbb2005 bops, running on an HP ProLiant DL785 G5 server, the newest addition to the award-winning HP ProLiant product line, with eight quad-core AMD Opteron 2.7 GHz processors, 64 GB RAM and Microsoft Windows 2008, surpassing a result using the Sun JVM(3) on a near-identical system by nearly 14 percent, and a similarly sized IBM Power system using the IBM JVM(4) by 36 percent.

Comment: I believe you're thinking of a different kind of server than he is.  He's asking about server software for learning to develop servlets, best here is what is easy for him to setup and use, not necessarily the fastest.

Comment: @sparks I can see it being read that way- the question's vague- I took it as it was a generic "what's the best server for java"

Answer (score 2):

While Tomcat suffices for those starting out in Java Web Development, you might also try Sun [Glassfish](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/) as its got a good amount of features.

Answer (score 1):

The best server for what exactly?  Ubuntu Server is great...

Answer (score 1):

For testing and devvelopment purposes I have used WebLogic, WebSphere, Tomcat, JBoss, and Jetty. By far my most favorite is Jetty, it is so very simple. That is the only one on my dev machine at the moment.

It sounds like you are just starting out, in which case I would suggest keeping it simple. [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Weblogic